# How shuffle a file (which contains an array) before using it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using a std mp3 player in a webpage.  Their javascript function includes the following line:

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="playlist=http://..../mp3_playlist.txt" />
```

The file contains an array of mp3 file names (separated by new lines).

I want to shuffle the playlist so that it changes each time it's visited.

So I added a shuffle function:

```
var pList = new Array();
    $.get('http://..../mp3_playlist.txt', function(data){
            pList = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
            pList = shuffle(pList);
     });
```

What syntax should I use to insert this array ref into the function instead of the file name?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where's the documentation for "their javascript function"? It might not support passing an array of values directly.

Comment: How you do that, and indeed whether it's possible, depends entirely on the Flash MP3 player itself. It has chosen to accept a variable, called `playlist`, which points to a file. If that's the only way it will accept that variable, then you're out of luck unless you write your shuffled list back to a file (likely on a server) and pass the new URL (or modify the Flash...)

Comment: The only thing I could find when searching for "std mp3" was ["*Have you got a nasty case of HTML? 10% of Americans think web code is an STD - while 25% think MP3 is a robot from Star Wars*"](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2573666/One-ten-Americans-think-HTML-sexually-transmitted-disease-quarter-think-MP3-robot-Star-Wars.html). I doubt this is the MP3 player you're talking about. Can you specify *which*?

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.  This one I am using is:
http://flash-mp3-player.net/players/multi/documentation/

Comment: I now see that the above allows an "mp3" parm. instead (i.e. a list of urls), but this options doesn't seem to allow "titles" for each url.)